# Change PhpStorm's Darcula Theme with IE conditions

Tags: themes, phpstorm

As you can see in the picture below, any HTML that is inside of condition statements for IE have a green background and while it may be nice to distinguish it from HTML for all other web browsers, it bothers me. Is there a way to change this in the Darcula theme? I know I'd have to make a copy of the Darcula theme but I want to know what field to change in the theme.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This is a language injection (HTML in this particular case). Yes -- you can change background color for language injection (but it will affect all such places).

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you! Found it under __IDE Settings__ > __Colors & Fonts__ > __General__ > __Injected language fragment__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to mark this question as answered and for anyone else looking for an answer...

As LazyOne mentioned in his comment, this is a language injection so it can be found under **IDE Settings > Colors & Fonts > General > Injected language fragment**.